# How to sort column2 only but separated by Space and Remove Duplicates

Tags: excel

Thus anyone have idea on how to resolved this,
I have many Data to Sort, I want to Sort only Column 2 but separated by Space and also I want to delete duplicate values,

Is there any formula to fix this?
Please see Picture Below
[image]

Comment: On the surface of it, the only real solution would be using vba (or other code). Formulas (whether native or coded) can't delete data.  You could use formulas to extract what you want into another table, and then you could convert that to values, and then delete the original table. But, if you're looking to fully automate, vba is the way to go.

Comment: Hi Spinner, hmm... do you have any sample output that can help me to fix this ?

Comment: Yeah... SO isn't a free coding service. It's purpose is for programmers to help other programmers (even if the asker is a complete novice). That means you need to make an attempt, show your work, and explain why it's not working and/or not doing as you'd hoped.

Comment: This view you sent looks like it is an output of a pivot table.  If this is the case, ask the person you got data from to sort the data by the column you want, before sharing it with you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found this Answer on Google, And it Helps me to fix the Problem

```
 Sub SortAndRemoveDuplicates()
Dim Rng         As Range
Dim RngArea     As Range
Dim sortRng     As Range
Dim lr          As Long
Dim i           As Long
Dim startRow    As Long

If Selection.Columns.Count > 1 Or Selection.Column <> 2 Then
    MsgBox "Please select data in column B only and then try again...", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If

On Error Resume Next
Set Rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 1)
On Error GoTo 0

If Rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

startRow = Selection.Cells(1).Row
lr = startRow + Selection.Rows.Count - 1

For Each RngArea In Rng.Areas
    Set sortRng = RngArea.Resize(, 2)
    sortRng.Sort key1:=sortRng.Cells(1), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
Next RngArea

For i = lr To startRow Step -1
    If Cells(i, 2) = Cells(i - 1, 2) Then
        Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```